# How to grab height of object tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just need to get the height of the content of an object tag when assuming the object is a webpage(on the same site.)

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks guys! I know there's a way to do it.

**EDIT**

```
<object id="blogs-and-stuff" data="blog/index.php" class="blog-stuff" type="text/html" style="width:900px; margin-left:50%;">
```

I want the height of index.php in the preceeding, not the height of ".blog-stuff".

```
$(".blog-stuff").height() //does not return what I need.
```

**EDIT EDIT**

Im trying to grab the height of the webpage inside the object tag and apply it to the object tag. This would increase the size of the object to show the entire webpage its holding rather than using scroll bars. Overflow is not working as planned.
[This screen shot shows only the object with the webpage in it](http://screencast.com/t/QwpW2WuP)

Sorry for the confusion guys.

Comment: Can you clarify, what the object is? Give an example. Right now I understand that you want to get the height of a webpage

Comment: I want the height of a webpage, thats inside of an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Access the content of Object

The real challenge seem to be how to access the content of the Object element. The solution I found is to use the `contentDocument` property of the `object` element. I put together a small test case where you log the height of the `object` content.

```
document.getElementById("object_id").contentDocument.body
```

*Make sure the `object` content is loaded before you try and access its height.*

```
<object id="test" data="test.html" ></object>
<button id="button">Log height</button>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#button").click(function() {
         console.log(document.getElementById("test").contentDocument.body.getBoundingClientRect().height)
    });
</script>
```

However, you will run into problem if try to load an external URL in your object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

---

Then there are a few different methods that will get the height of an HTML element.

### **Pure JavaScript options:**

***element.style.height***

```
document.getElementById("input_id_here").style.height;
```

Description:

> The height CSS property specifies the height of the content area of an
>   element. The content area is inside the padding, border, and margin of
>   the element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

***element.getBoundingClientRect().height***

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Description:

> Returns a text rectangle object that encloses a group of text
>   rectangles.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

***element.clientHeight***

```
element.clientHeight;
```

Description:

> Returns the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding
>   but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin.
>
> clientHeight can be calculated as CSS height + CSS padding - height of
>   horizontal scrollbar (if present).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight

***HTMLelement.offsetHeight***

```
document.getElementById("input_id_here").offsetHeight;
```

Description:

> Height of an element relative to the element's offsetParent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight

### **jQuery options**

***height("input_selector_here")***

```
$("input_selector_here").height()
```

Description:

> Get the current computed height for the first element in
>   the set of matched elements.

https://api.jquery.com/height/

***outerHeight()***

```
$("input_selector_here").outerHeight()
```

Description:

> Get the current computed height for the first element in
>   the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally
>   margin. Returns a number (without "px") representation of the value or
>   null if called on an empty set of elements.

https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

***innerHeight()***

```
$("input_selector_here").innerHeight()
```

Description:

> Get the current computed height for the first element in
>   the set of matched elements, including padding but not border.

https://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

Comment: yes, I know how to grab the height of an object. Im trying to get the height of the content in an object. my object is resulting in scrollbars vertical-wise. These responses are all shooting out the current height of the surrounding object

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your content looks like? Is it a webpage inside an iframe?

Comment: I put a portion of the code on the question. I can grab a screenshot if needed.

Comment: @AaronLoften I did some more testing and added some more to my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Wow. GREAT STUFF! I had to do some tinkering with it due to some weird setting on the page being included. Seriously. You didnt have to do all this research and testing. I appreciate it. ALOT. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I do not like jQuery so my answer will use native javascript....

```
document.getElementById('your-object-id').getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Comment: I tried this and it resulted the same as jquery did. This is returning the height of the object but not the height of whats in the object.
I will clarify in an edit to my description

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsById("object").style.height`

This should be the fastest solution, as it does not rely on an extra function call like the other jQuery solutions.